# Errors using enum type in C++ code

Tags: c++, enums, omnet++

I just implemented this class :

```
class MIXIM_API DSRCmsgID : public cObject
{
public:
    /** @brief Constant with all values set to 0. */
    static const DSRCmsgID ZERO;

public:

    //int msgID;
     enum msgID {
        DSRCmsgID_reserved  = 0,
        DSRCmsgID_alaCarteMessage   = 1,
        DSRCmsgID_DSRCmsgID    = 2,
        DSRCmsgID_DSRCmsgIDVerbose = 3,
        DSRCmsgID_commonSafetyRequest   = 4,
        DSRCmsgID_emergencyVehicleAlert = 5,
        DSRCmsgID_intersectionCollisionAlert    = 6,
        DSRCmsgID_mapData   = 7,
        DSRCmsgID_nmeaCorrections   = 8,
        DSRCmsgID_probeDataManagement   = 9,
        DSRCmsgID_probeVehicleData  = 10,
        DSRCmsgID_roadSideAlert = 11,
        DSRCmsgID_rtcmCorrections   = 12,
        DSRCmsgID_signalPhaseAndTimingMessage   = 13,
        DSRCmsgID_signalRequestMessage  = 14,
        DSRCmsgID_signalStatusMessage   = 15,
        DSRCmsgID_travelerInformation   = 16
    };

private:
  void copy(const DSRCmsgID& other) {msgID = other.msgID; }

public:
    /** @brief Default constructor. */
    DSRCmsgID()
        : msgID() {}

    /** @brief Initializes a DSRCmsgIDinate. */
    DSRCmsgID(enum msgID )
           : msgID(msgID) {}

    /** @brief Initializes DSRCmsgIDinate from other DSRCmsgIDinate. */
    DSRCmsgID(const DSRCmsgID& other)
        : cObject(other) { copy(other); }

    /** @brief Returns a string with the value of the DSRCmsgIDinate. */
    std::string info() const;

};


inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DSRCmsgID& DSRCmsgID)
{
    return os << "(" << DSRCmsgID.msgID << ")";
}

inline std::string DSRCmsgID::info() const {
    std::stringstream os;
    os << *this;
    return os.str();
}
```

I got these errors:

- error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token -> at the copy function;
- error: ‘enum DSRCmsgID::msgID’ is not a non-static data member of ‘DSRCmsgID’ -> at the constructor and initializer;
- error: invalid use of ‘enum DSRCmsgID::msgID’-> at the return os line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`msgID` is currently declared as a *type*, not a variable - you could just change:

```
enum msgID {
    DSRCmsgID_reserved  = 0,
    // ...
    DSRCmsgID_travelerInformation   = 16
};
```

to:

```
enum {
    DSRCmsgID_reserved  = 0,
    // ...
    DSRCmsgID_travelerInformation   = 16
} msgID;
```

however it would probably be more convenient to declare a type:

```
enum MsgID {  // the type of this enum is `MsgID`
    DSRCmsgID_reserved  = 0,
    // ...
    DSRCmsgID_travelerInformation   = 16
} msgID;      // and we also have an instance variable of this type, `msgID`
```

then you can also fix this constructor:

```
DSRCmsgID(enum msgID )
       : msgID(msgID) {}
```

which would become:

```
DSRCmsgID(MsgID msgID )
       : msgID(msgID) {}
```

Comment: okay thank you, solved those errors but it still returns this error : "  error: use of enum ‘ID’ without previous declaration" at the initializer method. I tried to declare it previously but it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, your declaration of `DSRCmsgID(enum msgID )` is incorrect - you should probably declare a type for this enum. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: Allright @Paul R thanks you for quick and right response!